# check radio button again in radio group android

Tags: android, kotlin, radio-button, radio-group

I am using a radio group containing two radio buttons like below:

```
  <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dp_16"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_16"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbDebitCard"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_regular"
                        android:textColor="@color/txt_color_heading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/debit_card"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Pay with Card"/>


                <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_1"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_16"
                        android:background="@color/divider_line"/>

                <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbCash"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_regular"
                        android:textColor="@color/txt_color_heading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/cash"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_16"
                        android:text="Cash"/>

            </RadioGroup>
```

In my kotlin code I am showing a bottom sheet when rbDebitCard is clicked and changing the check by ischecked=false when closing the bottom sheet.
which perfectly unchecks the radio button.

The issue is, when I am clicking on the same radio button again, it is not getting checked. However, the bottom sheet is opening.

If i click on the other radio button(which obviously gets checked) and then again clicking on the first button then it is getting checked and opening the bottom sheet. But once again I close the bottom sheet and click on the radio button, it is not getting checked.

For reference, below is the kotlin code:

```
//pay with card
        rbDebitCard.setOnClickListener {
            rbDebitCard.isChecked = true
            paymentMode = "Card"
            onBraintreeSubmit(clContainer)
        }

        //Cash
        rbCash.setOnClickListener {
            paymentMode = "Cash"
        }

 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == BundleConstants.REQ_CODE_PAYMENT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // use the result to update your UI and send the payment method nonce to your server
            val result: DropInResult = data!!.getParcelableExtra(DropInResult.EXTRA_DROP_IN_RESULT)
            Log.e("payment result nonce", result.paymentMethodNonce?.nonce)

            makePayment(result.paymentMethodNonce?.nonce)
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // the user canceled
            rbDebitCard.isChecked = false
        } else {
            // handle errors here, an exception may be available in
            val error = data!!.getSerializableExtra(DropInActivity.EXTRA_ERROR) as Exception
            rbDebitCard.isChecked = false
        }
    }
}
```

adding the check change listener to the radio button looks like below:

```
 rgPayment.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
        when(checkedId){
            R.id.rbDebitCard->{
                rbDebitCard.isChecked = true
                paymentMode = "Card"
                onBraintreeSubmit(clContainer)
            }

            R.id.rbCash->{
                paymentMode = "Cash"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is with  `rbDebitCard.isChecked = false`
I replaced this with `rgPayment.clearCheck()`.

With this i think in a radiogroup some check must be maintained by the radio group also which is independent of the check assigned to a radio button manually.

However, this thing solved the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the id of the Radio Group and use radio group checkedchangedlistener like this -

```
val checkedRadioButton = group?.findViewById(group.checkedRadioButtonId) as? RadioButton
        checkedRadioButton?.let {

            if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked)
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "RadioGroup: ${group?.contentDescription} RadioButton: ${checkedRadioButton?.text}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

Comment: nope. It is checking the radio button again and again. As a result the bottom sheet is also opening again

Comment: Check which radio button is checked. You can put an if condition. Based on that, call your BootomSheet

Comment: I have also done the same thing for braintree payments like you. It works

Comment: You might be missing something

Comment: I have updated the question with the check change listener code. can you have a look.

Comment: Sure. Checking.

Comment: actually buddy this is not the answer, the answer is that you have to call radiogroup.clearCheck() instead of radiobutton.isChecked = false. However, upvoted for the help :)

Comment: Couldn't understand your exact problem as your question was too complicated to understand. But the correct way to get radiobutton checked is to get a changedlistener. Anyways,  thanks for the vote